# CentOS server - monitor the number of SMTP processes, send email if over X?

Tags: smtp, centos, ps

My company has a colocated CentOS server that hosts a dozen websites.  We use Plesk for management but I personally mostly work via terminal.  This weekend, an email account for one of our client's domains was compromised and the server started sending out spam.  We were blacklisted for spamming and it caused some of our sites to be down while I figured out what was going on.

Obviously, I would like to avoid this happening again.  I didn't set up the server in the first place - running http hosting and mail hosting on the same IP for multiple websites probably isn't the best setup because all it takes is one dumbass client with a weak email password to hose multiple websites.

As a short term fix, I'm wondering if it's possible to have a script monitor the number of SMTP processes and email me if it's over a certain threshold?  When the server was spamming it was running about 80 SMTP processes, which was what tipped me off that it was being used as a spam server.  Also, any ideas for long-term handling of this situation?  The server has a block of 8 IPs.

Thanks for your help, any advice/input is welcome.  I'm a LAMP developer, not a full-time *nix admin.  I'm thinking

have a cron job trigger every 5 minutes 
pipe #ps -A output to a file 
read the file and count the number of occurrences of the string 'SMTP' via regex
send email if needed

but dang, that seems kind of convoluted :/

Answer (score 1):

Got it worked out.  Here's the shell script that counts the number of SMTP processes and if there are more than ten, sends an email with count:

```
#!/bin/bash  <- change as appropriate for your shell
NUMSMTP = $(ps ax | grep 'smtp' | wc -l)
if [[ $NUMSMTP -gt 10 ]] ; then
    echo "the server has $NUMSMTP processes running" | mail -s "subject" admin@example.com
fi
```

Scheduled it via cron to run every five minutes via crontab at /etc/crontab, using

```
*/5 * * * * /path/to/script.sh
```

And win :)